# Postgresql not running?

Tags: postgresql

I installed PostgreSQL and trying to connect:

```
$ psql
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?


$ ps aux | grep postg
```

`$ sudo service postgresql start` - does not result.

```
$ psql -U ivan -h localhost msg_proxy
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Why? My iptables seems ok:

```
$ sudo iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Mon Feb  6 13:31:17 2017
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [43867:5867960]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [34820:18177695]
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Feb  6 13:31:17 2017
```

Output of `sudo netstat -pant | grep postgres` is empty

Comment: Can you see a PostgreSQL Process running, when calling `ps aux | grep postgres`

Comment: @BenH no. empty output

Comment: which OS do you use?

Comment: "Connection refused" usually means there is no server listening on that TCP port on that IP address.  (it could also mean a firewall blocked the connection)  Probably postgresql is either not running, or not configured to listen on that address and/or port.

Comment: @BenH ubuntu 16.04

Comment: try looking at this: [link](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/pg_ctlcluster.8.html)

Answer (score 0):

Respodning to this old question maybe is not the best idea, as this question lucks of a few information like:

- Operating System
- PostgreSQL Version
- From where are you trying to connect (same machine?)
- Not well described problem and trials you performed (does not result?)

As the output indicates, either PostgeSQL is not running either not accepting connections:

1. If in your processes do not see the PostgreSQL, are you sure
   PostgreSQL is there?

   ps aux | grep postgres
2. If your PostgreSQL is located to another server inside same network
   try the following:

   psql -h db-address -d db-name -U username -W